# Can Git GPG program be used for s3cmd?

Tags: git, cygwin, gnupg, amazon-s3

My ultimate goal is to be able to put files onto my Amazon EC2 server. After a month of failed attempts at getting SSH access to the server, I have decided to try s3cmd and eventually migrate files from my S3 bucket to my EC2 server. When running `s3cmd --configure` in CygWin, I enter the following path for the GPG program.

```
Path to GPG program: "C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin/gpg.exe"
```

I have Git installed, and gpg.exe at this location seems to run, but I get this error:

```
ERROR: Test failed: GPG program not found
```

Can I use Git's `gpg.exe` file with s3cmd in Cygwin? Should I install some other GPG program?

Comment: What does the s3 config file show for that value? I'm afraid I don't know its location on a Windows box, but on linux / mac its default is: `~/.s3cfg` I strongly suspect this is as simple as s3cmd choking on parsing the path from the config file. Either the quotation marks  or the space in the path. To debug, try these versions of the path as well: `"C:/Program\ Files (x86)/Git/bin/gpg.exe"` and `C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin/gpg.exe`. One escapes the space. The other leaves out the quotes.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions... The first version is detected as an MS-DOS style path, and I tried the second one before, which resulted in "`GPG program not found`", although now when I try it, it gives me "`Test failed: Encryption verification error`"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the S3cmd prompts, in its exact text, is:

> Path to GPG program [/usr/bin/gpg]:

Upon hitting enter, this value will be used. `gpg.exe` can be run from `cygwin\bin\gpg.exe`, because [`cygwin/usr/bin` maps to `cygwin/bin`](https://superuser.com/a/451624/140203) (The reason I couldn't find it before because I didn't know this.)