# Why can I see a file that I own in CygWin but not in Windows Explorer?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, cygwin, file-permissions

I installed Cygwin in Windows 7 and was browsing through the `c:/cygwin/` directory in the Cygwin terminal. There exists a directory `bin/` at the path `c:/cygwin/usr/bin`, but I cannot find this folder in Windows Explorer, and I cannot `ls` this path in CygWin unless I am already in the `usr/` folder. It doesn't seem to be hidden, and my Windows user account is the owner of both files. Is there any explanation for why/how this folder can only be reached in a certain way?

File permissions:

```
molga@Win7Dell /usr
$ ls -l -d "c:/cygwin/usr"
drwxr-xr-x 1 molga Domain Users 0 May 17 10:53 c:/cygwin/usr

molga@Win7Dell /usr
$ ls -l -d bin
drwxr-xr-x+ 1 molga Domain Users 0 Jul 20 08:17 bin
```

Comment: Are you sure it’s not hidden? Have you tried selecting the *show hidden* option in Folder Options?

Comment: @Synetech I tried that, and it was still hidden...

Comment: Can you open it in Explorer by directly typing it into the address-bar? What about the command-prompt? Can you `cd` to it in `cmd`?

Comment: It's not accessible through the Explorer address bar or command prompt, either.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cygwin's `mount` command will show you that `/usr/bin` is mapped to `C:\Cygwin\bin` (which means `/usr/bin` is the same as `/bin`). Windows Explorer and Command Prompt of course don't know about Cygwin mounts.

Comment: @FlyingMolga it's actually not obvious, so it's really silly to say you feel silly for not realising that.  It is very confusing that cygwin has a usr subdirectory with no bin within it,  but that its own usr directory maps to bin.

Comment: https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#mount-table has info on /usr/bin vs /bin